# Comparison under more conditions

Tags: r, subset, lapply

according to my last question i have an new belonging question. After Editing my post and ask there and wait abot a week i want to try it here again.

This time with a better example:

```
Equip<- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6)
Notif <-c(1,1,3,4,2,2,2,5,6,7,9,9,15,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19)
rank <- c(1,1,2,3,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Component <- c("Ventil","Motor","Ventil","Ventil","Vergaser","Vergaser","Bremse",
"Lichtmaschine","Bremse","Lichtmaschine","Bremse","Motor","Lichtmaschine",
"Bremse","Bremse","Motor","Vergaser","Motor","Vergaser","Motor",
"Vergaser","Motor")    

df <- data.frame(Equip,Notif,rank,Component)
```

`Equip` is my subject and `rank` the actual visit number. `Component` is the subject what have to be looked for.

I want to have an output like this:

If an `Equip(subject)` was visited 2 times( `rank` 1 and 2) look by all `Equip`s with `rank` 1&2 , if there is any `Component` which was regarded the first and the second time.

If an `Equip(subject)` was visited 3 times (`rank` 1 ,2 and 3) for this look by all `Equip`s, if there is any `Component` list up 3 times like  `Equip` 1, `rank` 1, `Component` Motor, `Equip` 1, `rank` 2, `Component` Motor, `Equip` 1, `rank` 3, `Component` Motor

The output should have the name of the `Component`, like True "Motor"

I have a code but with this, i can just compare the 1 and the 2 visit, the 2 and the 3 together and so on( i cannot split up again with the ranks, like Equips with 2 ranks, Equips with 3 ranks and so on)

the code is this:

```
a <- lapply(split(df,df$Equip),function(x){      
ll <- split(x,x$rank)                    
 if(length(ll)>1 )
ii <- intersect(ll[[1]]$Component,ll[[2]]$Component ) ## test intersection
  else 
   ii <- NA
 c(length(ii)> 0 && !is.na(ii),ii)                                              
})
b <- unlist(a)
c <- table(b,b)
rowSums(c)
```

Hopefully you can help me. Please ask if there are any questions.

according to your question about the output, and to your way of solution,

```
     Equip Component   V1 idx
1:     1    Ventil  TRUE   3
2:     2        NA  False  1
3:     3        NA  False  3
4:     4        NA  FALSE  2
5:     5        NA  FALSE  3
6:     6        NA  FALSE  6
```

Something like that, but if its easier, Equip and idx is not neccessarilly needed

for Equip with 2 ranks:

```
TRUE          FALSE
  0             1
```

for Equip with 3 ranks:

```
TRUE          FALSE
 1              2
```

for Equip with 6 ranks:

```
TRUE          FALSE
 0              1
```

Comment: Ok in clearly words. First i want to look for the 2 times visited Equips. So the output i want to get is, if there are any items(Components) listen up in the first rank and in the second rank as well. If there is such an item output should be TRUE and the name of the component. For 3 times visited Equips the same but it should be taken a look if there is any component which were used in rank 1,2,3 etc...... the code above which i mentioned, cannot make difference for looking just for 2 times visited Equips, 3times visited Equips and so on..  Maybe now understand what i mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the output I think would be of interest to you. Its using `data.table`.

First, we create a `data.table` from your `data.frame df` with `keys = Equip, Component` as follows.

```
require(data.table) # load package
# then create the data.table with keys as specified above
# Check that both these columns are already sorted out for you!
dt <- data.table(df, key=c("Equip", "Component"))
```

Second, we create a function that'll give the desired output for a given rank query (2, 3 etc..)

```
this.check <- function(idx) {
    chk <- seq(1, idx)
    o <- subset(dt[, all(chk %in% rank), by=c("Equip", "Component")], V1 == TRUE)
    if (nrow(o) > 0) o[, idx:=idx]
}
```

What does this do? Let's run this for `rank=1,2`. We run this by:

```
> this.check(2)
# output
   Equip Component   V1 idx
1:     1    Ventil TRUE   2
2:     5    Bremse TRUE   2
```

This tells you that for `Equip = 1 and 5`, there are `Components = Ventil and Bremse` with `rank = 1 and 2`, respectively (indicated with idx=2). You also get the column `V1 = TRUE`, even though I, as @Carl pointed out already, don't understand the need for this. If you require, you can change the column names of this output by using `setnames`

Third, we use this function to query `ranks=1,2`, then `ranks=1,2,3` .. and so on. This can be accomplished with a simple `lapply` as follows:

```
# Let's run the function for idx = 2 to 6. 
# This will check from rank = 1,2 until rank=1,2,3,4,5,6
o <- lapply(2:6, function(idx) {
    this.check(idx)
})
> o
[[1]]
   Equip Component   V1 idx
1:     1    Ventil TRUE   2
2:     5    Bremse TRUE   2

[[2]]
   Equip Component   V1 idx
1:     1    Ventil TRUE   3

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL
```

It shows that for `rank=1,2` and `rank=1,2,3` you have some `Component`. For others there's nothing = `NULL`.

Finally, we can `bind` all of these together using `rbind` to get one single `data.table` as follows:

```
o <- do.call(rbind, o)
> o
   Equip Component   V1 idx
1:     1    Ventil TRUE   2
2:     5    Bremse TRUE   2
3:     1    Ventil TRUE   3
```

Here, `idx=2` are the `Component` that satisfies `rank=1,2` and `idx=3` are the ones that satisfy `rank=1,2,3`.

**Putting it all together:**

```
this.check <- function(idx) {
    chk <- seq(1, idx)
    o <- subset(dt[, all(chk %in% rank), by=c("Equip", "Component")], V1 == TRUE)
    if (nrow(o) > 0) o[, idx:=idx]
}

o <- do.call(rbind, lapply(2:6, function(idx) {
    this.check(idx)
}))
```

I hope this helps.

**Edit:** (After series of exchanges in comments, this is the new solution I propose. I hope this is what you are after.)

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key=c("Equip", "Component"))
dt[, `:=`(e.max=max(rank)), by=Equip]
dt[, `:=`(ec.max=max(rank)), by=c("Equip", "Component")]
setkey(dt, "e.max", "ec.max")
this.check <- function(idx) {
    t1 <- dt[J(idx,idx)]
    t2 <- t1[, identical(as.numeric(seq_len(idx)), as.numeric(rank)), 
              by=c("Equip", "Component")]
    o <- table(t2$V1)
    if (length(o) == 1) 
        o <- c(o, "TRUE"=0)
    o <- c("idx"=idx, o)
}
o <- do.call(rbind, lapply(2:6, function(idx) this.check(idx)))

> o
#      idx FALSE TRUE
# [1,]   2     1    0
# [2,]   3     2    1
# [3,]   4     1    0
# [4,]   5     1    0
# [5,]   6     1    0
```

Comment: this highly goes to that what i need. So if an Equip has rank 1,2,3 then the component should have been in all ranks the same Component otherwise my analysis gets distort. Maybe for this it could be possible to make subsets of Equips with 2 ranks, then Equips with 3 ranks etc.?? Because as my pasted code i just want to read out the number of Equips ( in this case the true's) and the components( the number could be higher because more then 1 component could be in rank 1 and 2 as well) the data set i am working on have more then 80k rows so i really need it like i do at the end....

Comment: Maybe you know something else or build up on your given code. But up to now really i big thanks for your work =) THANKS a LOT

Comment: Hmm. i will try it again because do not know how to show a desired output. Maybe it would be possible to split the data also for Equips with 2 rank, with 3 ranks and so on and then compare them like if in this splitted groups is in every rank any same component. Something like this i mean.

Comment: I edited my whished output according to your code  in my first question on the top. Thank you for your help

Comment: Which TRUE you mean?? :P   Sorry.. ofcourse it was a mistake i corrected it. Sorry for that and thanks for your help

Comment: Oh shit! sorry about that you are right Yes i think you got what i mean. Do you have any solution for that? Big thanks =)

Comment: Arun do you have maybe any idea on that? it would be really helpful. It would be also O.K. , if i Just get an TRUE, so as far as i look for what i need, it is just about the TRUE

Comment: OK. i edit my post. Hopefully you understand what i mentioned.

Comment: Ok. sorry for that. The ouput refers now to the question above. Hopefully you understand now what i mean. Thank you

Comment: I split up for rank, means Equips with 2 ranks. Then i compare the components, which were used in the first and second rank is there ANY Component listen up in the first and in the second visit? IF YES the output is TRUE if not THE output is FALSE .    SAME for Equips with 3 ranks.. Is there any Component listen up in the first, second and in the thrid rank, if yes, TRUE if not FALSE. so the sum of TRUE and FALSE is the number of Equips which have rank 2. Example... in the Data there are 3 Equips which have rank = 3, One of them have the same Component in 1,2,3 rank, Output TRUE, and 2 not..

Comment: and so for themn, the OUTput is FALSE... got it?

Comment: Arun do you know now what i mean or shall i post maybe in a new answer what i exactly mean? I realls need your help for that

Comment: Ah O.K now it got your problem. Of course you are right in that case, that Equip 6 has rank=3 as Well, but Equip 6 has more ranks as well. What i mean is, that the Equips which have the same maximum number of ranks have to put together, so Equip 6 has his own "group" because it is the only Equips with the rank=6 as the maximum number of rank.... So the thing is to seperate the Equips with a different number of ranks.

Comment: Ok here we are =) That is what i mean. Thanks a lot for that. I will comprehend it and maybe if there is something unclear, i will ask. But at the moment, BIG THANKS TO YOU

Answer (score 0):

If I make an array of your data, columnwise, as

```
foo<-cbind(Equip,Notif, rank, Component)
eqp<-1 # later, loop over all values
foo[c( which(  foo[,1]==eqp & (foo[,3]==1 | foo[,3]==2) ) ),4]
[1] "Ventil" "Motor"  "Ventil"
```

Feed those results to `table` and extract items with count ==2

Clearly any item which shows up twice is what you want.
This is not an answer I'd recommend using, since tools like `ddply` and `aggregate` will do this much more cleanly, but I want to be sure that this is the answer you're after, assuming a loop over `eqp` values in the original `Equip` .

Comment: First, thanks for your answer, i want to know, if there is any item used in rank 1 ( in one Equip) also used in rank2 ( in the same Equip) the anser should be something like, TRUE and then the name of the item. ( for a twice visited Equip( the info how many visits is rank))...... then with adapting the code a little bit, i want to gain the information, if a three times visited Equip, rank 1,2,3 if there is any item listen up in every of these visits. Know what i mean?  Thanks a lot

Comment: Why bother with "TRUE" since only the desired equipment names will be returned in the first place?

Comment: because there could be more than 1 Components in the first ans second rank.  So i have 2 Component names in 1 Equip. that is ok but i have to know the number of Equips as well... You know what i mean ?